An Inequality Involving Gegenbauer Polynomials Integrated against a power of $1-t^2$.
Are there exact expressions for the integral
$$ \int_0^1 (1-t^2)^{s+1/2} C_k^{(s)}(t)\; dt, $$
where $C_k^{(s)}(t)$ are the Gegenbauer polynomials, as defined here. I am mainly interested when $2s$ is a positive integer, for applications in the study of spherical harmonics. Alternatively, what kind of asymptotics exist as $k \to \infty$, for a fixed $s$.

Let, $$I = \int_0^1 (1-t^2)^{s+1/2} C_k^{(s)}(t)\; dt, $$
For $k=2n$ , the answer is straightforward thanks to the evenness of the integrand.
$$I_{2n} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{s+1/2} C_{2n}^{(s)}(t)\; dt $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)(1-t^2)^{s-1/2} C_{2n}^{(s)}(t)\; dt $$
Now, using $C_0^{(s)}(t)=1$ and $C_2^{(s)}(t) = 2s(s+1)x^2-s$, we get,
$$I_{2n}=  \frac{1}{4(s+1)}\left((2z+1)\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{s-1/2} C_0^{(s)}(t) C_{2n}^{(s)}(t)\; dt-\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{s-1/2} C_2^{(s)}(t) C_{2n}^{(s)}(t)\; dt.\right)  $$
By orthogonality, we get
$$I_{2n}=\begin{cases} 
-\frac{\pi 4^{-s} \Gamma(2s)}{2 \Gamma(s + 2) \Gamma(s)}, & \text{if } n=0, \\
\frac{\pi 4^{-(s + 1)} s (2s + 1)^2 \Gamma(2s + 1)}{\Gamma(s + 3) \Gamma(s)}, & \text{if } n=1,\\
0. & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
For $k=2n+1$ it is more complicated. Substitute $x=t^2$,
$$I_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-x)^{s+1/2} C_{2n+1}^{(s)}(\sqrt{x})\; dt. $$
Using 7.319.2 in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, we can solve this in terms of the hypergeometric function ${}_3F_2$
$$I_{2n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n\Gamma(s+\frac32)\Gamma(s+n+1)}{n! \Gamma(s)\Gamma(s+2)}{}_3F_2(-n,s+n+1,1;\frac{3}{2},s+2;1).$$
If you're interested in asymptotic properties, you can almost certainly simplify this more. Maybe try using the fact that $s+n+1$ and $s+2$ differ by an integer and manipulating 16.3.1, 16.3.3. and 16.3.4 in the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions.
